# WooCommerce - модификация формы трекинга заказов

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В WooCommerce есть форма трекинга заказа `form-tracking.php`, есть 2 поля email и номер заказа (order id). Мне нужно, чтобы форма искала только по order id. Файл с формой я скопировал в дочернюю и убрал поле email, но есть еще файл проверки заполнения полей `includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-order-tracking.php`. Как мне сделать так, чтобы отключить проверку на ввод email? Если полезу изменять файл, то после обновы все вернётся, как было.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.6.0/templates/order/form-tracking.php - файл формы.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.6.0/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-order-tracking.php - файл проверки на ввод полей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, править файлы стороннего плагина - последнее дело. Надо пользоваться хуками, которые WP и WC предоставляют в изобилии.

Ниже представлен плагин, который делает то, что вам нужно.

Создайте папку `/wp-content/plugins/kagg-track-order`. Поместите в неё главный файл плагина `plugin.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * KAGG Track Order
 *
 * @package           kagg-track-order
 * @author            KAGG Design
 * @link              https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1331178
 * @license           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * @wordpress-plugin
 *
 * Plugin Name:       KAGG Track Order
 * Description:       Plugin modifies WooCommerce Track Order form.
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Requires at least: 5.0
 * Requires PHP:      5.6.20
 * Author:            KAGG Design
 * Author URI:        https://kagg.eu/en/
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       kagg-track-order
 * Domain Path:       /languages/
 */

/**
 * Filter woocommerce locate template.
 *
 * @param string $template      Template.
 * @param string $template_name Template name.
 * @param string $template_path Template path.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function kagg_track_order_woocommerce_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
    if ( 'order/form-tracking.php' === $template_name && 'woocommerce/' === $template_path ) {
        return __DIR__ . '/' . $template_path . $template_name;
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'kagg_track_order_woocommerce_locate_template', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Filters whether to call a shortcode callback.
 *
 * Returning a non-false value from filter will short-circuit the
 * shortcode generation process, returning that value instead.
 *
 * @param false|string $return Short-circuit return value. Either false or the value to replace the shortcode with.
 * @param string       $tag    Shortcode name.
 * @param array|string $attr   Shortcode attributes array or empty string.
 * @param array        $m      Regular expression match array.
 */
function kagg_track_order_pre_do_shortcode_tag( $return, $tag, $attr, $m ) {
    if ( 'woocommerce_order_tracking' !== $tag ) {
        return $return;
    }

    ob_start();
    kagg_track_order_output( $attr );

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_filter( 'pre_do_shortcode_tag', 'kagg_track_order_pre_do_shortcode_tag', 10, 4 );

/**
 * Output the shortcode.
 *
 * @param array $atts Shortcode attributes.
 */
function kagg_track_order_output( $atts ) {
    // Check cart class is loaded or abort.
    if ( is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $atts        = shortcode_atts( [], $atts, 'woocommerce_order_tracking' );
    $nonce_value = wc_get_var( $_REQUEST['woocommerce-order-tracking-nonce'], wc_get_var( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], '' ) ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'woocommerce-order_tracking' ) ) { // WPCS: input var ok.

        $order_id = empty( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ? 0 : ltrim( wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ), '#' ); // WPCS: input var ok.

        if ( ! $order_id ) {
            wc_print_notice( __( 'Please enter a valid order ID', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        } else {
            $order = wc_get_order( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_order_tracking_order_id', $order_id ) );

            if ( $order && $order->get_id() ) {
                do_action( 'woocommerce_track_order', $order->get_id() );
                wc_get_template(
                    'order/tracking.php',
                    [
                        'order' => $order,
                    ]
                );

                return;
            } else {
                wc_print_notice( __( 'Sorry, the order could not be found. Please contact us if you are having difficulty finding your order details.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            }
        }
    }

    wc_get_template( 'order/form-tracking.php' );
}
```

Создайте в папке подпапки `woocommerce/order` и поместите в `order` файл `form-tracking.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Order tracking form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/form-tracking.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $post;
?>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); ?>" method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-track-order track_order">

    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'To track your order please enter your Order ID in the box below and press the "Track" button. This was given to you on your receipt and in the confirmation email you should have received.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first"><label for="orderid"><?php esc_html_e( 'Order ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="orderid" id="orderid" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Found in your order confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last"><label for="order_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Email you used during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row"><button type="submit" class="button" name="track" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button></p>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-order_tracking', 'woocommerce-order-tracking-nonce' ); ?>

</form>
```

Так выглядит структура файлов плагина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Активируйте плагин KAGG Track Order в админке и убедитесь, что всё работает.

Как это происходит? В главном файле плагина есть несколько хуков, которые делают необходимое.

`kagg_track_order_woocommerce_locate_template` фильтрует шаблон формы Track Order и подставляет туда путь к файлу `form-tracking.php` внутри плагина. Этот файл представляет слегка изменённую форму WC, из которой мы убрали поле ввода email.

`kagg_track_order_pre_do_shortcode_tag` перехватывает обработку шорткода `[woocommerce_order_tracking]` и отдают в виде строки результат функции `kagg_track_order_output`, которая представляет собой модифицированную `\WC_Shortcode_Order_Tracking::output`, из которой мы убрали обработку email.

Репозиторий плагина находится тут: https://github.com/kagg-design/kagg-track-order